# Is there a source for clear and amber glass bottles that can handle pressure?

Tags: bottling, carbonation

Looking for a place I can get soda bottles from ( looking to brew my own soda ) either twist top or screw top. Looked all around the internet but can't seem to find the right thing.

Comment: I would search 'brew bottle' on amazon. You can typically find an assortment of colors (clear, blue, green, brown) of glass bottles that can hold pressure, but won't screw. Flip-top is probably your best bet if you don't have a capper.
A related post: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/279/reusing-twist-off-bottles mentions reuse, but not if the new caps are abled to be screwed-off.

Comment: Bottles have a rating for volumes of CO2.  Different bottles have different ratings.  You absolutely do not want bottles not-rated-for-pressure - but these are often the most prevalent and lowest in cost.  Try googling "wholesale screwtop beverage bottle supplies" for your region.  I suggest you might consider normal "beer-type" bottles and caps.  You can also get caps for champagne bottles, these need a special capper-bell, but are great, I use them a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064OG6AO) not working?  These are 1/2-Liter, but I'm sure you can find other sizes.  Also recommend a visit to your local homebrew store.  If you're buying in bulk, they may have a discount, plus you support local business.

Update: So the title includes the restriction of "glass" but the body of the question does not.  So if you are looking for glass bottles, with twist off action, the answer is no.  Buy a $8.00 capper and enjoy.  Otherwise the link above to plastic bottles works well.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some swing tops:
[Swing Tops](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01I47DW50)

Or you can use some 750s for extra preasure and conveninet aging:
[750s](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005CI25EE)

Even a multicolored set: 
[WOW!!!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014HPO5T0)

Comment: None of these are screw or twist bottles.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using twist of bottles, they don't seal very well.

New Castle has capable clear bottles.  I would choke some down and wash the bottles if you don't like the swing type.

Comment: Me neither, seems like a poor choice.

Comment: I accidentally used one on a batch early on.  I took a swig right off the bottle.  It was practically vinigar.

Also, clear bottles let in way too much light.  It's gonna skunk your beer.

Answer (score 0):

Duvel amber bottles hold about 11 ounces and can handle about 4 vol of pressure, compared to 2.8 for most standard 12 ounce bottles.  The bottles I had were very heavy, squatty with very rounded edges.  I don't know if you can buy them commercially, I got mine emptying them one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best.  Go to your local homebrew store and ask them if they have something—either in stock or orderable—that'll fill your requirements.

Simple solutions notwithstanding, a 12 oz. beer bottle will most likely be able to handle the pressure and be the proper amber color.